# Boolean values import to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, csv, boolean

I have a .numbers spreadsheet with raw data that I export as csv and use a custom built import tool to import that data into my Rails app. I have some columns in Numbers where I just enter a `1` or `0` to indicate a boolean field.

I the following validates line on one of my models:

```
  validates :powered,
    inclusion: [true, false]
```

As the value being imported is `1` and I am checking if the value validates against `true` or `false` then this is obviously not validating and failing.

How, without changing the original spreadsheet or exported csv can I make `1`'s and `0`'s from the csv map to a standard boolean `true` or `false` in my Postgres DB and Rails app?

Comment: If you're already using a custom CSV import solution do the conversion *during import*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a callback to translate the `1` or `0` to `true` or `false`. Something like the following:

```
before_validation :powered_to_bool
...

def powered_to_bool
  self.powered = true if self.powered == 1
  self.powered = false if self.powered == 0
end
```

Comment: Will try this out tommorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The validation happens before the Model is saved to the DB, therefore the conversion (usually DB specific - MySQL will store booleans differently to Postgres) never occurs.

You may need to massage your values, when extracting from CSV and before validating, using a `before_validation` callback. Check out [ActiveRecord::Calbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) for more info.